# Does log2 (n)*(x) set compression limits.

Tags: compression

I may get all kinds of flags and penalties thrown at me for this. So please be patient. 2 questions

1. If the minimal number of bits to represent an arbitrary number of decimals is calculated by log2 (n)*(x)....n is range x is length, then you should be able to calculate max compression by turning the file into decimals by the>>> bin to dec.?
2. Is this result a law that one can not compress below the theoretical min compression limit, or is it an approximated limit?
   Jon Hutton

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a bit (ha) trickier. That formula assumes that the number is drawn from a uniform distribution, which is often not the case, but notably *is* the case for what is commonly called "random data" (though that is an inaccurate name, since data may be random but drawn from a non-uniform distribution).

The entropy H of X in bits is given by the formula:

```
H(X) = - sum[i](P(x[i]) log2(P(x[i])))
```

Where P gives the probability of every value `x[i]` that X may take. The bounds of `i` are implied and irrelevant, impossible options have a probability of zero anyway. In the uniform case, P(x[i]) is (by definition) 1/N for any possible `x[i]`, we have `H(X) = -N * (1/N log2(1/N)) = -log2(1/N) = log2(N)`.

The formula should in general not simply be multiplied by the length of the data, that only works if all symbols are independent and identically distributed (so for example on your file with IID uniform-random digits, it does work). Often for meaningful data, the probability distribution for a symbol depends on its context, and indeed a lot of compression techniques are aimed at exploiting this.

There is no law that says you cannot get lucky and thereby compress an individual file to fewer bits than are suggested by its entropy. You can arrange for it to be possible on purpose (but it won't necessarily *happen*), for example, let's say we expect that any letter is equally probable, but we decide to go against the flow and encode an A with the single bit 0, and any other letter as a 1 followed by 5 bits that indicate which letter it is. This is obviously a *bad* encoding given the expectation, there are only 26 letters and they're equally probable but we're using more than `log2(26) ≈ 4.7` bits on average, the average would be `(1 + 25 * 6)/26 ≈ 5.8`. *However*, if by some accident we happen to actually get an A (there is a chance of 1/26th that this happens, the odds are not too bad), we compress it to a single bit, which is much better than expected. Of course one cannot rely on luck, it can only come as a surprise.

For further reference you could read about [entropy (information theory) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)).

Comment: Also the probability of values only gives you the zeroth-order entropy. There can be higher-order correlations of specific combinations of adjacent values, which is where most of the compression of modern compressors come from. This is most commonly exploited by looking for repeated strings of values (where "values" usually means bytes).